# Can I cache data loading in R?

Tags: r, caching, startup

I'm working on a `R` script which has to load data (obviously). The data loading takes a lot of effort (500MB) and I wonder if I can avoid having to go through the loading step every time I rerun the script, which I do a lot during the development.

I appreciate that I could do the whole thing in the interactive `R` session, but developing multi-line functions is just so much less convenient on the `R` prompt.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
d <- read.csv("large.csv", header=T) # 500 MB ~ 15 seconds
head(d)
```

How, if possible, can I modify the script, such that on subsequent executions, `d` is already available? Is there something like a `cache=T` statement as in `R` markdown code chunks?

Comment: `cache=T` pragma would be a nice enhance suggestion, and similar to what Python does with decorators (but only on fn calls with immutable arguments).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sort of.  There are a few answers:

1. Use a faster csv read:  `fread()` in the `data.table()` package is beloved by many.  Your time may come down to a second or two.
2. Similarly, read once as csv and then write in compact binary form via `saveRDS()` so that next time you can do `readRDS()` which will be faster as you do not have to load and parse the data again.
3. Don't read the data but memory-map it via package `mmap`. That is more involved but likely very fast.  Databases uses such a technique internally.
4. Load on demand, and eg the package `SOAR` package is useful here.

Direct caching, however, is not possible.

*Edit:* Actually, direct caching "sort of" works if you save your data set with your R session at the end.  Many of us advise against that as clearly reproducible script which make the loading explicit are preferably in our view -- but R can help via the `load()` / `save()` mechanism (which lots several objects at once where `saveRSS()` / `readRDS()` work on a single object.

Comment: It still takes too long to be efficient, but the solution is to prepare intermediate datasets which keep these parts of the table which are required for the analysis and then to only save/load those.

Comment: Nr 2 above would be the most logical solution and pair it with using a call to `exists` provided you want to iteratively re-source the script into the global workspace. E.g. `if(!exists("d")){if(files.exsits(rds){#load rds} else {#load csv, save as rds}}`

Answer (score 3):

Package ‘R.cache’ [R.cache](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.cache/R.cache.pdf)

```
    start_year <- 2000
    end_year <- 2013
    brics_countries <- c("BR","RU", "IN", "CN", "ZA")
    indics <- c("NY.GDP.PCAP.CD", "TX.VAL.TECH.CD", "SP.POP.TOTL", "IP.JRN.ARTC.SC",
        "GB.XPD.RSDV.GD.ZS", "BX.GSR.CCIS.ZS", "BX.GSR.ROYL.CD", "BM.GSR.ROYL.CD")

    key <- list(brics_countries, indics, start_year, end_year)
    brics_data <- loadCache(key)
    if (is.null(brics_data)) {
      brics_data <- WDI(country=brics_countries, indicator=indics, 
                        start=start_year, end=end_year,  extra=FALSE,                 cache=NULL)
      saveCache(brics_data, key=key, comment="brics_data")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `exists` to check if the object is present and load conditionally, i.e.:

```
if (!exists(d))
{
  d <- read.csv("large.csv", header=T)
  # Any further processing on loading
}

# The rest of the script
```

If you want to load/process the file again, just use `rm(d)` before sourcing. Just be careful that you do not use object names that are already used elsewhere, otherwise it will pick that up and not load.

Comment: You might require to wrap `d` inside `''`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up some of the common ways of caching in R in ["Caching in R"](https://www.r-bloggers.com/caching-in-r/) and published it to R-Bloggers. For your purpose, I would recommend just using `saveRDS()` or `qs()` from the ['qs'](https://cran.r-project.org/package=qs) (quick serialization) package. My package, ['mustashe'](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mustashe), uses `qs()` for reading and writing files, so you could just use `mustashe::stash()`, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not a good idea to relate an answer mainly to links which  may get broken in the future.